# Neural network input normalization by mean / standart deviation : how to do it?

Tags: neural-network, normalization, denormalization

I am consufed on how to normalize the inputs / outputs for a regression neural network using (Gaussian normalization ? ) mean & standart deviation normalization technique :

Most importantly, I Normalize from which data ?

Let me explain :

let's say i have these training data on a  2 input neurons, 2 hidden neurons , 1 output neuron:

```
[input1 : 10][input2: 5]
[input1:  30][input2: 255]
```

do i normalize by column(neuron), or from all the inputs data ?
Is the mean for input neuron 1 =

```
(10+30)/2
```

or

```
(10+30+5+255)/4 ?
```

Try both with weird result using the typical XOR example (only 1s and 0s in the traning data), where i was actually loosing great accuracy when normalizing.

Comment: Imagine you have car's price on `input1` and its color (somehow encoded) on `input2` - obviously adding these two doesn't make any sense. Anyway, this is off-topic. Please try CrossValidated or ComputerScience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalization is to keep each dimension of input data in a certain range so usually it should be done in column. There are several ways for normalization. For example, linear normalization: It's the most common an easiest method and often used when the data is centered. It's counted by (V-Vmin)/(Vmax-V). And Gaussian normalization is counted by (V-Vavg)/Std.

Comment: alright thanks a lot :) any idea why using normalization on XOR data woûd recude accuracy ?

Comment: Actually each dimension in XOR data is in the same range (its value is 0 or 1) so it's unnecessary to use normalization.